# Does the zPosition property of a C4Shape take a moment to start working?

Tags: c4

if I do

```
zPosition = 3;
```

and then right away I run a method that does

```
string = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", (NSInteger)shape.zPosition];'
label.text = string;'
```

then the label displays an incorrect value for the zPosition. 
however if I run my method after a delay then it works.

what's going on there?
does zPosition take a moment to kick in?  or am I just doing something the wrong way?

here's a gist example of what I'm talking about https://gist.github.com/4670390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, YES, it takes a split second.

The answer as to "why" this is happening, is that the animation duration was implicitly being set to 0.0001 seconds in the api. Your immediate call to `[self updateLabels]` was actually being called before the `zPosition` properties were finished animating.

This is actually a bug I've now tracked in C4, I've fixed it in the [full project that's available on github](https://github.com/C4Framework/C4iOS/) but it will be a while before this makes it into the installer / project template.